# Connection String formation for Android to SQLServer Connectivity

Tags: android, sql-server-2008

I am trying to connect to SqlServer 2008r2 database whith Android.

It seems my connection string is not properly getting formed.

I am having following Error:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection to the
>   host 10.0.2.2, named instance 14graficali\mssqlserver20081433 failed.
>   Error: "java.net.SocketException: Permission denied". Verify the
>   server and instance names and check that no firewall is blocking UDP
>   traffic to port 1434.  For SQL Server 2005 or later, verify that the
>   SQL Server Browser Service is running on the host.

My SqlInstance:

[image]

Connection String which i formed:

```
String dbName = "AndroidDB";
     String serverip="10.0.2.2";
     String serverport="1433";
     String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://"+serverip+"\\14GRAFICALI\\MSSQLSERVER2008"+serverport+";databaseName="+dbName+"";
```

**Whole Code in which i am implementing it:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


     String dbName = "AndroidDB";
     String serverip="10.0.2.2";
     String serverport="1433";
     String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://"+serverip+"\\14GRAFICALI\\MSSQLSERVER2008"+serverport+";databaseName="+dbName+"";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        TextView tvData=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvSelectedData);

        try {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver").newInstance();
            Connection conn =DriverManager.getConnection(url);                   

            Statement statement=conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultSet=statement.executeQuery("select * from UserMaster");
            while(resultSet.next()){
                tvData.setText(" Data1 : "+resultSet.getString(1)+"  Data 2 : "+resultSet.getNString(2));
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            tvData.setText(e.getMessage());
        }



    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are Few Steps That need to be foolwed in case when we are connecting Android to directly a SQLServer.

I have mentioned each and every detailed steps in my answer over here:

[Class not found although particular jar is added in project (android to sqlserver without webservice)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18672012/class-not-found-although-particular-jar-is-added-in-project?answertab=active#tab-top)

Please follow the stages and i am sure you will overcome all the errors.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your AndroidManifest.xml file under your android project, open it and add this line :

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```