# Connect to SQL Server through android

Tags: android, sql-server

At the very first **I would like to know that *"Is it possible to connect android application to SQL Server??"***

If yes, then I am facing some problem with it. **I have added jtds-1.2.5.jar**

Here is my **MainActivity:**

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
EditText e1;
Button b1;
TextView t1;

String str = null;
String conUrl = null;
String uname,pass;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    e1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    str = "SELECT [Name] from user_mast where username = 'a'";

    abc();

    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            //querySQL(str);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "In Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

void abc()
{
    try{
        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        uname = "sa";
        pass = "123";

    ///////// This is the problem statement It is not get executed..
        Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://server:1433/AlphaHotel;user="+ uname +";password=" + pass);

        Statement statement=connect.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs=statement.executeQuery(str);

        while(rs.next()){
        t1.setText(rs.getString(0));
        }
        connect.close();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
 @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
       getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
       return true;
   }
```

}

Here is the **error Logcat :**  (*Error might be there on first two line only*)

```
12-31 06:40:33.884: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(2376): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
12-31 06:40:34.973: W/System.err(2376): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
12-31 06:40:34.973: W/System.err(2376):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
12-31 06:40:34.973: W/System.err(2376):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
12-31 06:40:34.983: W/System.err(2376):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
12-31 06:40:34.983: W/System.err(2376):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
12-31 06:40:35.033: W/System.err(2376):     at java.net.Socket.tryAllAddresses(Socket.java:108)
12-31 06:40:35.033: W/System.err(2376):     at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:177)
12-31 06:40:35.033: W/System.err(2376):     at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:149)
12-31 06:40:35.033: W/System.err(2376):     at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SharedSocket.<init>(SharedSocket.java:259)
12-31 06:40:35.033: W/System.err(2376):     at  net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC2.<init>(ConnectionJDBC2.java:311)
12-31 06:40:35.063: W/System.err(2376):     at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:187)
12-31 06:40:35.063: W/System.err(2376):     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:175)
12-31 06:40:35.063: W/System.err(2376):     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:140)
12-31 06:40:35.063: W/System.err(2376):     at com.example.z.MainActivity.abc(MainActivity.java:61)
12-31 06:40:35.094: W/System.err(2376):     at  com.example.z.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:38)
12-31 06:40:35.094: W/System.err(2376):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
12-31 06:40:35.094: W/System.err(2376):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
12-31 06:40:35.094: W/System.err(2376):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
12-31 06:40:35.094: W/System.err(2376):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
12-31 06:40:35.094: W/System.err(2376):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
12-31 06:40:35.103: W/System.err(2376):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
 12-31 06:40:35.103: W/System.err(2376):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-31 06:40:35.103: W/System.err(2376):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-31 06:40:35.103: W/System.err(2376):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
12-31 06:40:35.113: W/System.err(2376):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-31 06:40:35.113: W/System.err(2376):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-31 06:40:35.113: W/System.err(2376):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-31 06:40:35.153: W/System.err(2376):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-31 06:40:35.153: W/System.err(2376):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-31 06:40:35.323: I/Choreographer(2376): Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.`
```

This is my **Manifest file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.z"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.z.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Kindly check out all the code and tell me

**What should I add.**

**What might be the problem is.**

Thank you.

Comment: may be you get some answers from [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18670320/connection-string-formation-for-android-to-sqlserver-connectivity)

Comment: Hey thxxxx Shaleen your link is very much GOOD. It helps me a lot. @Shaleen

Answer (score 4):

Try adding this to your onCreate method:

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

And don't forget your internet permission in your AndroidManifest file!

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about Android connection with SQL Server. But the error clearly says :

```
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

It means you are trying to create network connection on Main Thread which is not permitted on Android 4.0 or later.

Try to create network connection in background thread or in AsyncTask.

Read : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: So please tell me how to do that sir. @Brijesh Thakur

Comment: Ok but how to do AsyncTask? I dont know that tell me about it. @Brijesh Thakur

Comment: this thing looks weired. you should not access database server  directly on android, it is not good practice. use REST Web services .. i will suggest http://restsql.org/doc/Concepts.html

Comment: Is Anyone Knows what this error means :
    `12-31 09:26:46.613: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(6383): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection`